# JavaScript not executing if statements correctly for date input field in iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari

first time asking a question here myself. Today i ran into a wierd problem regarding javascript on IOS Safari. The Following Code only fails on IOS Safari. I don't know how to fix it, i don't have an iphone. The person i designed this contact form for does.

```
<label for="date">Select Date</label>
            <input type="date" id="date" name="date"><br>
            <select id="time" name="time">
                <option value="" disabled selected>select Time</option>
                <option style="display:none" class="earlyhour" value="10:00">10:00</option>
                <option style="display:none" class="earlyhour" value="10:15">10:15</option>
                <option style="display:none" class="earlyhour" value="11:00">11:00</option>
                <option style="display:none" class="earlyhour" value="11:15">11:15</option>

                <option style="display:none" class="latehour" value="15:30">15:30</option>
                <option style="display:none" class="latehour" value="16:15">16:15</option>
            </select>
            <script>
                document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (){
                    let myDateField = document.getElementById("date");
                    myDateField.addEventListener("change", () => {
                        let selectedDate = new Date(myDateField.value);
                        document.querySelectorAll(".earlyhour").forEach(a=>a.style.display = "none");
                        document.querySelectorAll(".latehour").forEach(a=>a.style.display = "none");
       
                        if (selectedDate.getDay() == 1 | selectedDate.getDay() == 3 | selectedDate.getDay() == 5){
                            //console.log("earlyhour");
                            document.querySelectorAll(".earlyhour").forEach(a=>a.style.display = "initial");
                        }
                        else if (selectedDate.getDay() == 2 | selectedDate.getDay() == 4 ){
                            //console.log("latehour");
                            document.querySelectorAll(".latehour").forEach(a=>a.style.display = "initial");
                        }
                        else if (selectedDate.getDay() == 0 | selectedDate.getDay() == 6 ){
                            alert ("The selected date is during out of office hours");
                            myDateField.value = '';
                        }
                    });
                });

            </script>
```

The wierd thing is, every single  if statement gets excuted the moment someone trys to enter something into the date input field and i don't know why that is.

I tried waiting for the dom to be finished loading, this did not help.